# WKWebView didFinish Navigation only seems to be called once

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

Once my WKWebView has finished loading I pull out the absolute URL and if it matches I load a button on the screen.

As expected it doesn't appear until I reach the matching URL which is the behaviour I want.

However if I navigate away from the page the button persists and I can't get my head around why.

Does anyone have any ideas:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        if (webView.url?.absoluteString == "https://www.myurl.co.uk/product/clock") {


            let settingsButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
            view.addSubview(settingsButton)
            settingsButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple;                   
            settingsButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            settingsButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 56).isActive = true
            settingsButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 56).isActive = true
            settingsButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -14).isActive = true
            settingsButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 14).isActive = true
            settingsButton.setNeedsLayout()
            settingsButton.layoutIfNeeded()
            settingsButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * settingsButton.bounds.size.width
            settingsButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"AR"), for: .normal)
            settingsButton.clipsToBounds = true
            settingsButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
            settingsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonTapped2(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)


    }else {
            settingsButton.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: You will need add code to remove the button once you navigate away.

Comment: Immediately after I posted this I realised I'd skipped out some code I deleted and put back in which is removeFromSuperview() which still doesn't work. Using the debugger, I can see that after every page load it's running through the function but when the URL doesn't match, the button isn't being removed from the view.

Comment: You're else is running?

Comment: @MwcsMac It is. So what I've done since this is move button creation and destruction into their own functions. The destruction does an `('if settingsButton != nil)` before `removeFromSuperview` Then set breakpoints throughout and followed the condition. It reaches the ELSE when the URL doesn't match however the 'settingsButton' has a value of nil so it skips `removeFromSuperView`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing my remove method to this:

```
func RemoveButton() {

    for view in self.view.subviews {

        if view.isKind(of: UIButton.self) {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }



    }
```